# A React child component that sets this.properties of its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders a child component. When the constructor for the child component is executed, it executes a handler (from the parent) that sets `this.value = value` in the parent. It does this because the parent requires access to some data from the child, which it uses at a later point in time when the parents `componentDidUpdate()` is called.

Is it acceptable to have a React component do behave like this?

I should point out that my example code does not illustrate that the child is actually rendered via a render prop, which is where the params data actually comes from and why the parent doesn't have access to it as it comes from the render prop component.

**PARENT**

```
handleParams = (param) => {
  this.params = params
}

render() {
  return (
    <Child handleParams={this.handleParams} />
  )
}
```

**CHILD**

```
constructor(props) {
  this.props.handleParams(this.params)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  This pattern extends beyond React and can be used in many other contexts.  When one part of the system needs information from another part it either has no access to directly, or which has not been created yet (or both), providing a method as a means to get a hold of external dependencies is common.

Honestly I would only be worried if you were trying to set properties on the parent directly.  And then not because of the parent/child relationship, but because it becomes harder to reason about how changes propagate throughout the system and you have less control over those changes (e.g. you could provide a mechanism to prevent changes under certain conditions through a method, where this isn't possible when modifying properties directly).